# Should I reference MVVM framework in the Model layer?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, architecture

I spent a long time avoiding contamination of the Model layer with "WPF stuff". Of course XAML is banned from anything but the View from the start, but I get a bit confused when it comes to ViewModels and Models.

As I see it now, if you have a layer architectural pattern, so EVERY layer is spanned by this architecture. So, as the very MVVM name suggests, you could reference it in Model, layer, right?

Other thing I'm starting to figure out: MVVM seems to be independent from WPF, right? I mean, they work nicely together, you can use MVVM framework in the Model layer without referencing any WPF assembly, as far as I know.

So the question is:

> Is it considered OK or smelly to reference MVVM Framework in Model layer, and why?

(just for the record I'm using MVVM Light)

Comment: MVVM is (View <= ModelView <=> Model) right? Then View is independent at all and on Model level we can use something from VM. Yes, MVVM is independent from WPF, you can use it and with WinForms, but WinForms not really ready for it ^_^

Comment: I know what MVVM is, but what exactly do you mean by "MVVM framework"?

Comment: @GlenThomas Is some library with useful classes to implement the pattern. Examples: Caliburn.Micro, MVVM-Light, PRISM.

Comment: Since "model layer" is a made up distinction, you get to decide if referencing your view models from this is smelly or not.  You decide!

Answer (score 3):

In pure MVVV the **M** is the source of data for the **VM** yet it does not know about it, similarly the view is a representation of the **VM** but the **VM** does not know about the **V**. Keeping this sort of relation in mind, one would question the need to ever reference an MVVM framework from the Model, you do not need commanding or messenger or extended visual customization when it comes to the interactions with the Model, you simply consume it.

If you have a look at **[MVVM framework comparison sheet](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/MVVM+framework+comparison+sheet)**  you will see that none of these features include Model interaction.

The **VM** consumes the **M**, and the **V** consumes the **VM**.

MVVM is a pattern while WPF, Silverlight or Winforms are applications frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really have any references to your MVVM Frameworks, as they are part of infrastructure. While many of the current frameworks work on multiple platforms (Silverlight, WPF, UWP, WinPhone), they are often still bound to a certain technology or framework (i.e. last time I've watched Prism 5.0 region support was limited to WPF not supporting WinPhone/UWP).

Your "Model" layer would contain your business logic (aka domain model/layer) and should be independent of infrastructure concerns (UI Framework, Database implementations, MVC or Server technologies).

In case you have to change the MVVM Framework you would not only have to update your ViewModels but also your Model/Domain Layer. And that's bad, as you shouldn't have to update your domain, when you change infrastructure technology.